# Grails - SSL and Spring security core

Tags: http, grails, ssl, https, spring-security

I would like to have my application running exclusively with SSL turned on. 
I am using the Spring Security core plugin.

This is how I attempt to do it in `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort = 8080
grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort = 8443
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [ '/**' : 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL']
```

I was expecting this to cause redirects every time I would try to access a Url using HTTP. 
However, I am never redirected, and can navigate through both HTTP and HTTPS. I may add I am starting my application using `grails run-app -https`

Am I getting this all wrong ?

Any suggestion is most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a custom filterchain declared in your config?

you might need to add 'channelProcessingFilter' to your chain in that case

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using the forceHttps option

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any wildcards, so the definition is literally matching the root URL (`/`), but nothing below it (`/foo`).  What you want is:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [ '/**' : 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL']
                                                             ^^
```

(You can clearly see the wildcards in [the documentation](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/latest/#channelSecurity) :-)

Finally, if your server is behind a load balancer or other firewall that hides the protocol, check that same page for instructions on checking the header.

Comment: I am really sorry, I edited my question but I had the wildcards already in my code. I am trying this on localhost on a Fedora system if that matters.